# A question on Fontaine's periods rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a complete discrete valued field of characteristic zero with perfect residue field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers, $C$ the completion of an algebraic closure of $K$ and $\mathcal{O}_C$ its ring of integers. Fontaine defines in "[Le corps des périodes p-adiques](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1994__223__59_0/)" (see loc.cit, remark 1.2.4.(c))

$$\rm{A}_{inf}(\mathcal{O}_C|\mathcal{O}_K)$$

as the completion of $\mathcal{O}_K\otimes_{W(k)}W(\mathcal{O}_C^{\flat})$ for the topology defined by the ideal ($p$)+ker($\theta$), for a certain map

$$\theta :\mathcal{O}_K\otimes_{W(k)}W(\mathcal{O}_C^{\flat}) \to \mathcal{O}_C$$

where $W$ denotes Witt vectors, and $\mathcal{O}_C^{\flat}$ is the tilt of $\mathcal{O}_C$, that is, the projective limit of $...\to \mathcal{O}_C/p\mathcal{O}_C\to \mathcal{O}_C/p\mathcal{O}_C$ where the maps are Frobenius.

Later, in 1.3.3, it is claimed that

$$\rm{A}_{inf}(\mathcal{O}_C|\mathcal{O}_K)=\mathcal{O}_K\otimes_{W(k)}W(\mathcal{O}_C^{\flat})$$

(that is, there is no need of completing).

Why is this last claim true?

Comment: In $1.3.3$, Are you talking the definition $W_{\mathcal{O}_K}(R):=\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_W W(R)$ ?   I saw it [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_1994__223__59_0.pdf)

Comment: In 1.3.3 he says (with the above notation): "$\rm{A}_{inf}(\mathcal{O}_C|\mathcal{O}_K)$ qui s'identifie (...) à $W_{ \mathcal{O}_K}(\mathcal{O}_C^{\flat}) = \mathcal{O}_K\otimes_{W(k)}W(\mathcal{O}_C^{\flat})$". My question is why this identification.

Comment: It seems that this is addressed in Remark 1.2.4 c)-e), no?

Comment: I'm sorry for not been clear in the question. I do not know how to deduce it from remark 1.2.4 (why the kernel of Frobenius is of finite type in our case?). Also, parts (c) and( d) are clear (in fact I used (c) in the question), but I do not understand part (e).

Comment: Once you envelop the notation, I think that the fact that Frobenius kernel is finitely generated is clear: we are considering the kernel of the $p$-power map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{C}_K}/p \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{C}_K}/p$, and so the kernel consists of all elements represented by $x \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{C}_K}$ such that $x^p \in p\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{C}_K}$ - but this is precisely $p^{1/p}\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{C}_K},$ and the Frobenius kernel is $p^{1/p}\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{C}_K}/p\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{C}_K}$. I agree that (e) requires some further explanation, though.

Comment: @Pavel Čoupek Thank you for your comment. It solves my question, beacuse I know how to prove (e) for the particular case of $\mathcal{O}_C$ (essentially because ker($\theta$) is principal in this case, with the notation of loc.cit). I still do not know how to prove (e) in general, but this would be another question.